# Why dynamically set favicon disappear in IE11 when page has changed?

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I'm using angular 5.2.11. I have a branding service which send different URLs to favicon to application. I'm setting favicon when page is loading like this:

```js
const favicon = document.createElement('link');
favicon.setAttribute('type', 'image/x-icon');
favicon.setAttribute('rel', 'icon');
favicon.setAttribute('href', '//someUrlWherePlacedFavicon');
document.head.appendChild(favicon);
```

In IE11 when change page using route-service, favicon is setting from root of site "/favicon.ico". And even change from console not working. But if page reload then favicon begin changing normally.

I tried replace favicon link every time when page is changed but it didn't work.
I suppose that it's a bug of angular routing or IE11. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve setting the dynamic fav icon link using DOCUMENT class inside component.

In index.html set link tag

```html
<link id="appFavicon" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

and somewhere in your code import

```js
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: HTMLDocument) {}

this._document.getElementById('appFavicon').setAttribute('href', '/your/icon/path.ico');
```